# Find folders without a specific file in them

Tags: shell, unix, scripting

I have a number of folders in unix (with different names) that should all have the same few file names in them.  I want to find the folders that DON'T have a specific file:

For example:

```
A/
-->a.dat
-->b.dat
-->c.dat
B/
-->a.dat
-->b.dat
-->c.dat
C/
-->a.dat
-->c.dat
```

When looking for the `b.dat` file, how do I figure out that the `C` folder doesn't have it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Loop over each directory, and if it doesn’t have the file you’re looking for, add it to a list of results.

With the file structure you gave above, this script:

```
#!/bin/bash

result=()
for D in *; do
    if [ -d "${D}" ] && ! [ -f "${D}/b.dat" ]; then
        result+=("${D}")
    fi
done

echo "result is" "${result[@]}"
```

Prints:

```
result is C
```

Comment: Trying this for similar issue but my script just keeps (copied & pasted from above) giving error `myscript.sh: 3: Syntax error: "(" unexpected`

have tried **dos2unix** in case of bad eof but no difference.

Also, is there anyway to use this where the complete file name is not know, other than the end eg:
`*-1-.jpg`